# CSS rotateY with negatve degrees doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations

I'm trying to do animation that rotate the element in the Y axis. It works in Chrome and Firefox but it doesn't work in Safari.

I don't know what is the problem because, how I say before, it works good in Chrome, Firefox, Opera...

Only works in middle of animation, the other middle doesn't work :(

That's my code:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.book {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.book .page {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid green;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.book .page:nth-child(2n+1) {
   left: 0;
   transform-origin: right center;
   transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  }
.book .page:nth-child(2n) {
   right: 0;
   transform-origin: left center;
   transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
 
.book .page.page-no-1.active {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-2.active {
    animation: p-2-left 10s;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-2.no-active {
    animation: p-2-right 10s;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-3.active {
    animation: p-3-left 10s;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-3.no-active {
    animation: p-3-right 10s;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-4.active {
    animation: p-4-left 10s;
    z-index: 4;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-4.no-active {
    animation: p-4-right 10s;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-5.active {
    animation: p-5-left 10s;
    z-index: 5;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
.book .page.page-no-5.no-active {
    animation: p-5-right 10s;
    z-index: 4;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
   }

@keyframes p-5-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
 49% { z-index: 4; }
 50% { z-index: 5; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
}
@keyframes p-4-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
 49% { z-index: 5; }
 50% { z-index: 4; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
}
@keyframes p-3-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
 49% { z-index: 2; }
 50% { z-index: 3; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
}
@keyframes p-2-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
 49% { z-index: 3; }
 50% { z-index: 2; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
}

@keyframes p-5-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
 49% { z-index: 5; }
 50% { z-index: 4; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
}
@keyframes p-4-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
 49% { z-index: 4; }
 50% { z-index: 5; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
}
@keyframes p-3-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
 49% { z-index: 3; }
 50% { z-index: 2; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
}
@keyframes p-2-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
 49% { z-index: 2; }
 50% { z-index: 3; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">
 <div class="page page-no-5">Página 5</div>
 <div class="page page-no-6">Página 6</div>
 <div class="page page-no-3">Página 3</div>
 <div class="page page-no-4">Página 4</div>
 <div class="page page-no-1 active">Página 1</div>
 <div class="page page-no-2">Página 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-2, .page-no-3').removeClass('no-active').addClass('active')">Go up to page 3</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-4, .page-no-5').removeClass('no-active').addClass('active')">Go up to page 6</button><br>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-2, .page-no-3').removeClass('active').addClass('no-active')">Go down to page 1</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-4, .page-no-5').removeClass('active').addClass('no-active')">Go down to page 3</button>
```

And [JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/8237huwf/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think that the problem is not `z-index` in Safari. The problem in Safari is with `transform: rotateY(-Xdeg)` and negative degrees.

If I change `-180deg` for 180 deg in pages 3 and 5 it works good in Safari.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.book {
 position: relative;
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.book .page {
 position: absolute;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background: red;
 border: 1px solid green;
 -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
 -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
 backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.book .page:nth-child(2n+1) {
 left: 0;
 transform-origin: right center;
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.book .page:nth-child(2n) {
 right: 0;
 transform-origin: left center;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.book .page.page-no-1.active {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-2.active {
 animation: p-2-left 10s;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-2.no-active {
 animation: p-2-right 10s;
 z-index: 3;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-3.active {
 animation: p-3-left 10s;
 z-index: 3;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-3.no-active {
 animation: p-3-right 10s;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-4.active {
 animation: p-4-left 10s;
 z-index: 4;
 transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-4.no-active {
 animation: p-4-right 10s;
 z-index: 2;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-5.active {
 animation: p-5-left 10s;
 z-index: 5;
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.book .page.page-no-5.no-active {
 animation: p-5-right 10s;
 z-index: 4;
 transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

@keyframes p-5-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(180deg); z-index: 4; }
 49% { z-index: 4; }
 50% { z-index: 5; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
}
@keyframes p-4-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
 49% { z-index: 5; }
 50% { z-index: 4; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
}
@keyframes p-3-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(180deg); z-index: 2; }
 49% { z-index: 2; }
 50% { z-index: 3; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
}
@keyframes p-2-left {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
 49% { z-index: 3; }
 50% { z-index: 2; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
}

@keyframes p-5-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
 49% { z-index: 5; }
 50% { z-index: 4; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(180deg); z-index: 4; }
}
@keyframes p-4-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 4; }
 49% { z-index: 4; }
 50% { z-index: 5; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5; }
}
@keyframes p-3-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
 49% { z-index: 3; }
 50% { z-index: 2; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(180deg); z-index: 2; }
}
@keyframes p-2-right {
 0% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); z-index: 2; }
 49% { z-index: 2; }
 50% { z-index: 3; }
 100% { transform: rotateY(0deg); z-index: 3; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="book">
 <div class="page page-no-5">Página 5</div>
 <div class="page page-no-6">Página 6</div>
 <div class="page page-no-3">Página 3</div>
 <div class="page page-no-4">Página 4</div>
 <div class="page page-no-1 active">Página 1</div>
 <div class="page page-no-2">Página 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-2, .page-no-3').removeClass('no-active').addClass('active')">Go up to page 3</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-4, .page-no-5').removeClass('no-active').addClass('active')">Go up to page 6</button><br>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-2, .page-no-3').removeClass('active').addClass('no-active')">Go down to page 1</button>
<button onclick="jQuery('.page-no-4, .page-no-5').removeClass('active').addClass('no-active')">Go down to page 3</button>
```